# Term for a Non-Curving Path that is Not a Geodesic

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

[image: A square with 1 blue line segment and 2 red line segments. If the square is changed into a torus, the red lines form a path.]

Take that square and turn it into a torus. The red line segments link up to form a straight path connecting the points. However, the blue line segment is the geodesic between those points. Is there a term for paths like the red one?

Comment: The red one is also a geodesic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The blue line is *a* geodesic connecting the two points, and is also *the* shortest path, but it is not *the* geodesic, i.e. there is not just one geodesic.

A geodesic is *locally* the shortest path between two of its points. I.e. at any point on the geodesic, there is some open neighborhood of that point such that the shortest path between any two points within that neighborhood is the geodesic. Thus the red line is also a geodesic.

Comment: Now I am confused on what the difference between a geodesic and any continuous path is, but that was not my question. I'll do some more reading and try to figure out where I went wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ETam : The difference is that on a path that is not a geodesic, there are some points at which, no matter how small an open neighborhood about those points one looks at, there is a pair of points within the open neighborhood for which the shortest path between them is something other than the path in question.

Comment: Lets have the drawn path be a circle on a plane. For any two points on this path, the shortest path between them will be a chord. As those two points move closer together, the difference between the chord and the path becomes less. In other words, at the limit where the chord length is zero the chord lies on the path. If you say limits are not actually good enough and the shortest path has to lie be on the drawn path, then how do you handle end points? If you say that geodesics do not have endpoints and actually extend in both directions, how do you ensure the extended sided meet one another?

Comment: @ETam : "how do you ensure the extended sided meet one another?" I don't understand that question. A straight line with infinite extension in Euclidean space is a geodesic. How does you question apply to that?

Comment: @ETam : Another example of a continuous path that is not a geodesic is the boundary of a polygon in the plane. Look at a vertex where two edges meet. No matter how small you make the open neighborhood of that vertex, there will be points on the path within that neighborhood between which the shortest route is not the path in question.

Comment: A line on a Euclidean plane is the only exception since that geodesic is in a surface that extends infinitely. Instead, picture a geodesic on a torus where you extend both ends. If the two sides intersect, the result is a loop and everything is fine. If they don't intersect, the you have a problem. The geodesic would need to be infinitely long, with no self intersections, and exist in a finite amount of area. A fractal could do this since they can turn, a luxury geodesics don't have. Proof by contradiction: If the ends of a geodesic must meet up, or the geodesic has properties it cannot have.

Comment: @ETam : The line in the Euclidean plane is NOT an exception and is very very far from being the ONLY instance of a geodesic that extends infinitely in both directions. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

This is a *piecewise-geodesic* curve.

Comment: This answer is referring to the red and blue taken together.